# Pass install referrer code to React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, deep-linking

I am working on a React Native (0.71.8) application with Expo (SDK 48).

I have user groups in the application that allow any member to share an invite link through device Share API (send message, email etc).

I have created deep linking as explained by this article in the documentation: https://docs.expo.dev/guides/deep-linking/.

Now when the app is installed, the invite link opens in-app by default and user is added to the invited group.

But if the device doesn't have the app installed then the link reaches the server, which is configured to redirect to PlayStore (the app is only available on Android at the moment). In this case when the app is installed, the link never trigger's the deep linking listener so user is not added to the new group.

Is there any way this can be accomplished? Thanks in advance

I know of the existence of [Android PlayInstall Referrer Library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer/library) and it's [React Native Wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-play-install-referrer). This does fit my use case but it is only available for Android, and I want to maintain cross-platform compatibility.